# Accessing a database of ID numbers to validate against an entered number Python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to get the user to enter in a pin number (four numbers) which the database will then validate by looking at the customer ID's. At the moment, it works if I get the user to enter any of the ID pins and I program it so they can enter any ID for them to access, but I want them to access their own accounts. So if I enter, for example, Jeremy's unique pin, it will prompt me with a hello Jeremy message. At the moment, if I enter a four digit number, nothing simply happens. The code I have so far is :

```
def entryID():
    print("Hello")
    print()
    print()
    print("Welcome to the Northern Frock ATM system")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("In order for you to access the machine, you must enter a correct PIN")
    with sqlite3.connect("ATM.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select CustomerID from ATM")
        userIDs = cursor.fetchall()
    print(userIDs)
    UserID = input("Please enter your Customer ID. If you want to quit, type in 99999\n")
    if UserID == userIDs[0]:
        print('Hello smack')
    elif UserID == userIDs[1]:
        print("Hello joe")

    elif UserID == userIDs[2]:
        print("Hellow Snow")

    elif UserID == userIDs[3]:
        print("Hellow Moe")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchall()` returns a list of rows. Each row is a list of column values.

So `userIDs[0]` is the first row, i.e., something like `(1234,)`.

To access the actual value, you have to extract the first column from the row:

```
if UserID == userIDs[0][0]:
    ...
```

Please note that a query can return results in a random order unless you are using ORDER BY.

And it might be a better idea to store the customer names in the database, and load only the one you want:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT Name FROM ATM WHERE CustomerID = ?', [UserID])
for (name,) in cursor:
    print("Hello " + name)
else:
    print("wrong!")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Sorry to ask for further help, but when I know use two [][] is the first bracket going to be 0 to represent the singular row, and then the second bracket going to be 0-3? this was my understanding but I get an error of 'tuple index out of range'

Comment: As I said, `userIDs` is a list of rows. So `userIDs[n]` returns the n-th row.